# In what record company is Martin Garrix working now?

Tags: electronic-music

This past summer, Martin Garrix left Spinnin Records due to some reasons.

Now, he released 3 songs for free.

Does anyone know if he'll work alone, earning money just from the shows?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is confirmed yet, but people are saying that he is working under a new name "Area 21" possibly with another DJ. And now he is currently working under a new label named STMPD RCRDS.

[Martin Garrix announces new label STMPD RCRDS](http://www.dancingastronaut.com/2016/03/martin-garrix-announces-new-single-first-release-now-ive-found/)